# Is it dangerous to store HttpServletRequest objects in a queue for later processing?

Tags: java, servlets

So, I'm in a situation where I want to queue up a bunch of HttpServletRequest objects for asynchronous processing.  Put aside for the moment whether or not this is a wise strategy -- it actually is in this case, as I'm trying to retrofit an awful legacy system -- is this a dangerous thing to do?

What I'm concerned about here is whether or not the HttpServletRequest object holds onto any valuable resources or open connections that would lead to deadlocks or resource contention issues.

Assume here that I'm implementing a simple servlet with a doPost() method that takes the HttpServletRequest object, puts it into a LinkedBlockingQueue, and then sends the user some kind of stock response (like a 301 redirect to a confirmation page).

Thank you!

Comment: depends on your servlet container, but this sounds quite likely to blow up.  what information in the request will you be accessing?  put *that* stuff into your LBQ.

Comment: I'm using resin.  And yes, I'm aware I can do that, but for various reasons having to do with the legacy code, that is not as straightforward as it should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i've seen the internals of jetty, and i can assure you that moving that structure out of the current request would be very, very bad.  there's all kinds of current connection state which cannot be used outside of the current request.  i can't help but assume that would be true for pretty much any servlet container.

it sounds like you are planning on responding to the original request and then doing some additional processing.  i'd recommend copying the info you need from the original request into a separate data structure for the offline processing.  also, if you are dealing with code which requires an HttpServeletRequest, you can always mock up your own with the bits of data required by the code.

Comment: Basically, I'm needing to take a process that's currently synchronous, and make it asynchronous. All the values I need are in the HTTP headers, form parameters, and cookies.  The problem is, this set of values is ill-defined and buried in the legacy code.  I could try to "discover" what these values are and then refactor the business logic to take a new data structure instead of a HttpServletRequest object, but that would be a tedious, error-prone process.  I'd rather leave the legacy code alone and continue to pass in an HttpServletRequest object.  Mocking is an option, though.

Answer (score 1):

I did a very similar thing, and one of the problems I experienced is that Jetty seems to clean up stuff inside the `HttpServletRequest` at some point, leaving you with `null` return values from some of the `getXYZ` methods and even throwing NPEs at you for others.

So, yes, it is dangerous.

I now copy the stuff I need inside `doPost` and `doGet` and forget about the instance altogether.